# Concat elements of list of list in R to each other

Tags: r

I have a list of list which consist of 2 elements.

**Option one:**

*Element_1* of list of lists contains 2 or more lists.**(Heads)**

*Element_2* contains 1 list. **(Tails)**

Sometimes its the other way around.

**Option two:**

*Element_1* contains 1 list **(Heads)**.

*Element_2* contains 2 or more lists.**(Tails)**

I would like to connect the lists of *Element_1* with the *Element_2* and make a solution which is independent of the number of lists if possible in basic R (without additional packages).

Result would look like this:

**Option one:**

Head Nr1 out of *Element_1* + Tail Nr1 out of *Element_2*

Head Nr2 out of *Element_1* + Tail Nr1 out of *Element_2*

**Option two:**

Head Nr1 out of *Element_1* + Tail Nr1 out of *Element_2*

Head Nr1 out of *Element_1* + Tail Nr2 out of *Element_2*

I just cant wrap my **Head** around it...

Here is example Data:

```
list_of_lists<-list(list(number_of_routes = 3L, array_of_routes = list(structure(list(
    counter = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), lon = c(11.829831, 11.829711, 
    12.0418572, 11.8723945, 12.0805593, 12.6464814), lat = c(48.110075, 
    48.1091400999115, 48.354335199852, 48.5066475998145, 48.5474119998045, 
    48.5476380998044)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(counter = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), lon = c(11.829831, 
    11.8286025, 11.8257997, 12.1267218, 12.0857338, 12.6464814
    ), lat = c(48.110075, 48.1095313999115, 48.2453907998786, 
    48.2882288998681, 48.5457491998049, 48.5476380998044)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(counter = c(0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5), lon = c(11.829831, 11.8286025, 11.9679416, 
    12.1712435, 12.0857338, 12.6464814), lat = c(48.110075, 48.1095313999115, 
    48.0845023999175, 48.3018890998648, 48.5457491998049, 48.5476380998044
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"))), list(
    number_of_routes = 1L, array_of_routes = list(search_result = structure(list(
        counter = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), lon = c(12.0850511, 12.0805593, 
        12.0289344, 12.5555866, 12.6454471, 12.6464814), lat = c(48.5476380998044, 
        48.5474119998045, 48.6564452997775, 48.8944952997185, 
        49.1528600996545, 49.1531895)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
    ), class = "data.frame"))))
```

Provided Example look like this:

```
list_of_lists
[[1]]
[[1]]$number_of_routes
[1] 3

[[1]]$array_of_routes
[[1]]$array_of_routes[[1]]
  counter      lon      lat
1       0 11.82983 48.11008
2       1 11.82971 48.10914
3       2 12.04186 48.35434
4       3 11.87239 48.50665
5       4 12.08056 48.54741
6       5 12.64648 48.54764

[[1]]$array_of_routes[[2]]
  counter      lon      lat
1       0 11.82983 48.11008
2       1 11.82860 48.10953
3       2 11.82580 48.24539
4       3 12.12672 48.28823
5       4 12.08573 48.54575
6       5 12.64648 48.54764

[[1]]$array_of_routes[[3]]
  counter      lon      lat
1       0 11.82983 48.11008
2       1 11.82860 48.10953
3       2 11.96794 48.08450
4       3 12.17124 48.30189
5       4 12.08573 48.54575
6       5 12.64648 48.54764



[[2]]
[[2]]$number_of_routes
[1] 1

[[2]]$array_of_routes
[[2]]$array_of_routes$search_result
  counter      lon      lat
1       0 12.08505 48.54764
2       1 12.08056 48.54741
3       2 12.02893 48.65645
4       3 12.55559 48.89450
5       4 12.64545 49.15286
6       5 12.64648 49.15319
```

It demonstrates the **Option one**

The desired output for this option would look like this:

```
array_of_routes[[1]]
  counter      lon      lat
1       0 11.82983 48.11008
2       1 11.82971 48.10914
3       2 12.04186 48.35434
4       3 11.87239 48.50665
5       4 12.08056 48.54741
6       5 12.64648 48.54764
7       0 12.08505 48.54764
8       1 12.08056 48.54741
9       2 12.02893 48.65645
10       3 12.55559 48.89450
11       4 12.64545 49.15286
12       5 12.64648 49.15319

array_of_routes[[2]]
  counter      lon      lat
1       0 11.82983 48.11008
2       1 11.82860 48.10953
3       2 11.82580 48.24539
4       3 12.12672 48.28823
5       4 12.08573 48.54575
6       5 12.64648 48.54764
7       0 12.08505 48.54764
8       1 12.08056 48.54741
9       2 12.02893 48.65645
10       3 12.55559 48.89450
11       4 12.64545 49.15286
12       5 12.64648 49.15319

array_of_routes[[3]]
  counter      lon      lat
1       0 11.82983 48.11008
2       1 11.82860 48.10953
3       2 11.96794 48.08450
4       3 12.17124 48.30189
5       4 12.08573 48.54575
6       5 12.64648 48.54764
7       0 12.08505 48.54764
8       1 12.08056 48.54741
9       2 12.02893 48.65645
10       3 12.55559 48.89450
11       4 12.64545 49.15286
12       5 12.64648 49.15319
```

An example dataset for ***Option two** would look like this:

```
list_of_lists_other_way<-list(list(number_of_routes = 1L, array_of_routes = list(search_result = structure(list(
    counter = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), lon = c(12.0850511, 12.0805593, 
    12.0289344, 12.5555866, 12.6454471, 12.6464814), lat = c(48.5476380998044, 
    48.5474119998045, 48.6564452997775, 48.8944952997185, 49.1528600996545, 
    49.1531895)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"))), 
    list(number_of_routes = 3L, array_of_routes = list(structure(list(
        counter = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), lon = c(11.829831, 11.829711, 
        12.0418572, 11.8723945, 12.0805593, 12.6464814), lat = c(48.110075, 
        48.1091400999115, 48.354335199852, 48.5066475998145, 
        48.5474119998045, 48.5476380998044)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(counter = c(0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5), lon = c(11.829831, 11.8286025, 11.8257997, 
    12.1267218, 12.0857338, 12.6464814), lat = c(48.110075, 48.1095313999115, 
    48.2453907998786, 48.2882288998681, 48.5457491998049, 48.5476380998044
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
        counter = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), lon = c(11.829831, 11.8286025, 
        11.9679416, 12.1712435, 12.0857338, 12.6464814), lat = c(48.110075, 
        48.1095313999115, 48.0845023999175, 48.3018890998648, 
        48.5457491998049, 48.5476380998044)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = "data.frame"))))



[[1]]
[[1]]$number_of_routes
[1] 1

[[1]]$array_of_routes
[[1]]$array_of_routes$search_result
  counter      lon      lat
1       0 12.08505 48.54764
2       1 12.08056 48.54741
3       2 12.02893 48.65645
4       3 12.55559 48.89450
5       4 12.64545 49.15286
6       5 12.64648 49.15319



[[2]]
[[2]]$number_of_routes
[1] 3

[[2]]$array_of_routes
[[2]]$array_of_routes[[1]]
  counter      lon      lat
1       0 11.82983 48.11008
2       1 11.82971 48.10914
3       2 12.04186 48.35434
4       3 11.87239 48.50665
5       4 12.08056 48.54741
6       5 12.64648 48.54764

[[2]]$array_of_routes[[2]]
  counter      lon      lat
1       0 11.82983 48.11008
2       1 11.82860 48.10953
3       2 11.82580 48.24539
4       3 12.12672 48.28823
5       4 12.08573 48.54575
6       5 12.64648 48.54764

[[2]]$array_of_routes[[3]]
  counter      lon      lat
1       0 11.82983 48.11008
2       1 11.82860 48.10953
3       2 11.96794 48.08450
4       3 12.17124 48.30189
5       4 12.08573 48.54575
6       5 12.64648 48.54764
```

That means the output would look like this:

```
array_of_routes[[1]]

   counter      lon      lat
    1       0 12.08505 48.54764
    2       1 12.08056 48.54741
    3       2 12.02893 48.65645
    4       3 12.55559 48.89450
    5       4 12.64545 49.15286
    6       5 12.64648 49.15319
    7       0 11.82983 48.11008
    8       1 11.82971 48.10914
    9       2 12.04186 48.35434
    10       3 11.87239 48.50665
    11       4 12.08056 48.54741
    12       5 12.64648 48.54764

array_of_routes[[2]]

    1       0 12.08505 48.54764
    2       1 12.08056 48.54741
    3       2 12.02893 48.65645
    4       3 12.55559 48.89450
    5       4 12.64545 49.15286
    6       5 12.64648 49.15319
    7       0 11.82983 48.11008
    8       1 11.82860 48.10953
    9       2 11.82580 48.24539
    10       3 12.12672 48.28823
    11       4 12.08573 48.54575
    12       5 12.64648 48.54764

array_of_routes[[3]]

    1       0 12.08505 48.54764
    2       1 12.08056 48.54741
    3       2 12.02893 48.65645
    4       3 12.55559 48.89450
    5       4 12.64545 49.15286
    6       5 12.64648 49.15319
    7       0 11.82983 48.11008
    8       1 11.82860 48.10953
    9       2 11.96794 48.08450
    10       3 12.17124 48.30189
    11       4 12.08573 48.54575
    12       5 12.64648 48.54764
```

Comment: @akrun I updated the question with the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract (`[[`) the second (2) inner list element (`lst1`), Then use `Map` to `rbind` the corresponding elements of each of the `lst1`

```
lst1 <- lapply(list_of_lists, `[[`, 2)
do.call(Map, c(f = rbind, lst1))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
   counter      lon      lat
1        0 11.82983 48.11008
2        1 11.82971 48.10914
3        2 12.04186 48.35434
4        3 11.87239 48.50665
5        4 12.08056 48.54741
6        5 12.64648 48.54764
7        0 12.08505 48.54764
8        1 12.08056 48.54741
9        2 12.02893 48.65645
10       3 12.55559 48.89450
11       4 12.64545 49.15286
12       5 12.64648 49.15319

[[2]]
   counter      lon      lat
1        0 11.82983 48.11008
2        1 11.82860 48.10953
3        2 11.82580 48.24539
4        3 12.12672 48.28823
5        4 12.08573 48.54575
6        5 12.64648 48.54764
7        0 12.08505 48.54764
8        1 12.08056 48.54741
9        2 12.02893 48.65645
10       3 12.55559 48.89450
11       4 12.64545 49.15286
12       5 12.64648 49.15319

[[3]]
   counter      lon      lat
1        0 11.82983 48.11008
2        1 11.82860 48.10953
3        2 11.96794 48.08450
4        3 12.17124 48.30189
5        4 12.08573 48.54575
6        5 12.64648 48.54764
7        0 12.08505 48.54764
8        1 12.08056 48.54741
9        2 12.02893 48.65645
10       3 12.55559 48.89450
11       4 12.64545 49.15286
12       5 12.64648 49.15319
```

---

For the second case

```
lst2 <- lapply(list_of_lists_other_way, `[[`, 2)
unname(do.call(Map, c(f = rbind, lst2)))
[[1]]
   counter      lon      lat
1        0 12.08505 48.54764
2        1 12.08056 48.54741
3        2 12.02893 48.65645
4        3 12.55559 48.89450
5        4 12.64545 49.15286
6        5 12.64648 49.15319
7        0 11.82983 48.11008
8        1 11.82971 48.10914
9        2 12.04186 48.35434
10       3 11.87239 48.50665
11       4 12.08056 48.54741
12       5 12.64648 48.54764

[[2]]
   counter      lon      lat
1        0 12.08505 48.54764
2        1 12.08056 48.54741
3        2 12.02893 48.65645
4        3 12.55559 48.89450
5        4 12.64545 49.15286
6        5 12.64648 49.15319
7        0 11.82983 48.11008
8        1 11.82860 48.10953
9        2 11.82580 48.24539
10       3 12.12672 48.28823
11       4 12.08573 48.54575
12       5 12.64648 48.54764

[[3]]
   counter      lon      lat
1        0 12.08505 48.54764
2        1 12.08056 48.54741
3        2 12.02893 48.65645
4        3 12.55559 48.89450
5        4 12.64545 49.15286
6        5 12.64648 49.15319
7        0 11.82983 48.11008
8        1 11.82860 48.10953
9        2 11.96794 48.08450
10       3 12.17124 48.30189
11       4 12.08573 48.54575
12       5 12.64648 48.54764
```

Comment: I get Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) :  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: yep it works :) thank you. But this will only work for Option one. Is it possible to make a solution which would work for both options without "if" check for amount of elements to see which one has only one element?

Comment: almost there! the only problem it alway adds the parts as tails.

Comment: I think there is something wrong, it produces the same result several times. Ill add an dput for the option 2. Option 1 works.

Comment: @Andreas `Head Nr1 out of Element_1 + Tail Nr1 out of Element_2

Head Nr1 out of Element_1 + Tail Nr2 out of Element_2 `  Is the logic, that if there is one element, just do the rbind of that list element or if the number of elements are same, rbind the corresponding elements?

Comment: @Andreas If that is the case, both options will work with the update